# vertical-align bottom not work

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I need all text in `<a href="#"><strong>Home</strong><span>This is a home</span></a>` placed at bottom but css code not working.

css

```
a { text-decoration: none; color: #777; }

.menu {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu li a {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.menu li a span,
.menu li a strong {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

the live code here http://jsfiddle.net/wgjfL/

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say placed at the bottom are you meaning at the bottom of text under the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the `position:relative;` from the `menu li a` class and apply a `display:table-cell;` for it to work.

Here is the [WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/wgjfL/1/)

**The Code:**

```
.menu li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FBFBFB;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: auto;
}
```

To understand the full **Logic** of how and when to use vertical-align, refer to [THIS ARTICLE](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/).

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following on your main nav:

> clear: both;

This will ensure that your links will always be at the bottom of anything above it.

You can also use:

> float: left;

Then

> clear: none;

on the other elements. Which will force them not to wrap around the text.

Guy